# How to Split Pandas data for 2 decimals in object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

Consider a dataframe in Pandas, where one of the many columns have data that has TWO decimals in the column.
Like

```
13.343.00
12.345.00
98.765.00
```

How can one get a new column (float) where values are stored in only 1 decimal format stripping that last part of `14.234(.00)`.

Desired output should be a new column like

```
13.343
12.345
98.765
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the digits after the second period are not always 0s (and not always two), the following code is more robust:

```
df["col"] = df["col"].str.extract("(.+)\.[0-9]+").astype(float)
```

Comment: This can also work: df['col'].str.extract('(.+)\.')

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
print(df)
         col
0  13.343.00
1  12.345.00
2  98.765.00

df.col=df.col.str.rstrip('.00')
print(df)

      col
0  13.343
1  12.345
2  98.765
```

You can convert it back to `float` if you like by `astype(float)`

Note : You should not use this if you have all 0s example: `00.000.00` instead use the second solution.

**If the second decimal is not always 0 use:**

```
df.col.str.rsplit(".",1).str[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
#remove last 3 values
df['col'] = df['col'].str[:-3].astype(float)
```

Or:

```
#get values before last .
df['col'] = df['col'].str.rsplit('.', 1).str[0].astype(float)
```

Or:

```
#one or zero integer \d* \. and integer \d+ pattern
df["col"] = df["col"].str.extract("(\d*\.\d+)").astype(float)
```

Comment: But how about something like `.765.00`?

Comment: @DYZ - hmmm, I think I cannot see this data in data sample ;)

Comment: @DYZ - But for you - `df["col"] = df["col"].str.extract("(\d*\.\d+)").astype(float)`

Comment: (Taking a bow.)